# Mongodb: keeping a limited amount of data of a sorted array

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a document `data` of documents (containing readings) for each item in my collection:

```
{
    "_id": ...,
    "data": {
        "2016-07-24": {"reading1": 1},
        "2016-07-25": {"reading1": 2},
        "2016-07-26": {"reading1": 3}
    }
}
```

Data is added periodically with the same format.

The keys must be unique, as new data will replace old data (for example, `"2016-07-25": {"reading1": 9}` would replace the value listed above)

How do I keep only the most recent 10 entries (when keys are sorted)? Can I do this with a mongo query or should I use application-side logic?

Turning `data` into an array could work, but has the issue of having entries with duplicate dates.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/) array update operator does exactly what you're asking. Take a look at the [examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/slice/#slice-from-the-end-of-the-array) on the doc page.

Comment: That looks good. If I do this, I assume using `upsert` to update the data elements would be the right way to go?

Comment: helmy: the problem is that I need array elements to be unique based on the date. mongo doesn't seem to allow me to say something like "Update field X of the array element whose field Y is baz", which is what I'd have wanted.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that, and clarify.

Comment: It looks like having an array for this just isn't going to cut it. I'll probably use upsert to update values, and then `find` to check whether any need to be removed afterwards. Regardless, thank you for your help!

Comment: The $ positional operator may do what you want, but you haven't clarified your question... Take a look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118472/discussion-between-humanoid-and-helmy).